# select query from 2 tables with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have page where people can post `comments` and page where people can click "`follow`" on other people profiles (same as `LIKE` on `Facebook`)

I would like to have `SELECT` query that will post all the comments I have, but will order them with the follow way:

First, print the 2 newest `comments` (they must been posted this `week`) of the `lastest` people you click `FOLLOW`.

Second, post the rest of the posted, `order` them by `create-date`

(I'm using `linux time`)

Can you help me with the SQL query?

This is my current `SELECT` query. it pull all comment by `create-date`:

```
SELECT 
  id, userID, text, createDate 
FROM `comments` AS comment 
WHERE (comment.refID = 0) 
  AND (comment.pageName = 'yard') 
  AND 1=1 
ORDER BY comment.createDate DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

"`followers`" table looks like this:

```
userID  ownerID     createDate
1       2           1439019657
1       4           1438940399
```

(user 1 is following after user 2 and 4)

"`comments`" table looks loke this:

```
 id     userID  pageName    refID   text    createDate
220      1       yard       0       text1    1438030967
227      1       yard       0       text2    1438031704
228      1       yard       0       text3    1438031704
```

(`userID` - which user publish the comment. `refID` - always "`0`". `pageName` - always "`yard`")

So is this case, if I'm user number 1, than I would like to see the newest 2 comments of users 2 and 4 (only if they where made in the last `week`) and than to see all the rest of the comments (of `all users`) `order by date` (without , of course, the once that I already saw)

Comment: why `AND 1=1` condition??

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to split this up into 2 queries.. ..and I am guessing at some of the table relationships here..

```
// get the last 2 comments from followed users..
SELECT *
FROM comments
WHERE userID IN (
    SELECT ownerID
    FROM followers
    WHERE userID = ?
) ORDER BY createDate DESC
LIMIT 2

// then get the rest, removing already returned comments
SELECT *
FROM comments
WHERE id NOT IN (
    -- either put the above query in here
    -- or buuild an array of the 'id's when outputting the results above
    -- and use that in here to prevent them being returned again
) ORDER BY createDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(select com.userID,com.page,com.text
from followers as fol 
JOIN comments as com 
ON fol.ownerId=com.userId 
where 
(
  from_unixtime(com.createDate) BETWEEN
 (
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -14 DAY)  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
 )
Order BY com.createDate desc
)

Union

(select com.userID,com.page,com.text
 from comments as com
 where com.id NOT In
    (select com.id
     from followers as fol 
     JOIN comments as com 
     ON fol.userId=com.userId 
     where 
     (
      from_unixtime(com.createDate) BETWEEN
      (
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -14 DAY)  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
       )
     ) 
      Order BY com.createDate desc
    )
```

**Explanation:**
There are two queries merged in one using union.

1. Select statement will give all the data follower comments.
   this is accomplished using Join.
2. Select statement to get all the other comments then the comments of the          above 1st query.

> the only thing that is not clear is how you are deciding whether the
>   comments is been read by the user (Insufficient information)

Comment: Hi,
where is the part where you pull the only 2 last comments from every user I follow (with condition - the comment had to be posted during the last week)?

Comment: @Roi try this one according to ur above comments.

Comment: Try this and let me know if there is any problem.